# self submitting coldfusion form with two submits

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I have a coldfusion form that the user can Accept or Reject records. There are two "submit buttons"  on the page. The two submit buttons have different values. This is not the full code but an example. The page will not submit. There is not error message and the records are not updated, To me the cfif should work.

```
<cfif form.isupdate eq 1 
   <cfif form.go is 1>
      <cfquery name="acceptRecords" datasource="db">
        Update table....
      </cfquery> 
<cfif form.go is 2>
   <cfquery name="rejectRecords" datasource="db">
        UPDATE table...
       </cfquery>
<cfelse
<cfoutput>
 <form id="acceptReject" name="acceptReject" method="post" action="">
</cfoutput>
 <table class="action-table">
 <tr>
 <td align="left">Click on <img src="images/GoRed.gif" VALUE="1" ALT="Go" NAME="goAccept" style="border-style: none" id="goRedAcceptIMG" /> to <font color="red">ACCEPT</font> selected Network Tools.</td>
<td align="left">Click on <img src="images/GoRed.gif" VALUE="2" ALT="Go" NAME="goReject" style="border-style: none" id="goRedRejectIMG" /> to <font color="red">REJECT TRANSFER</font> selected Network Tools.</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="isupdate" value="1"/>
<!--- Output results--->
<table class="results-table" id="results">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th align="center"><img src="images/checkbox.gif" id="checkAll" name="checkAll"></th>
        <th>Tag#</th>
        <th>Serial#</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <cfoutput query="SearchResults" >
       <td>#ARnetworkToolSearchResults.currentrow#</td>
       <td align="right"><input name="selectedTools" type="checkbox" class="chkaction" id="#SearchResults.ID#" value="#SearchResults.ID#"/></td>
       <td>#SearchResults.BST_ID#</td>
       <td style="width:100px;">#SearchResults.SERIAL_NUM#</td>
 </tr>
    </cfoutput>
 </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</cfif>
```

Comment: The code you've included is a bit to superficial to be of much use. If you are having problems with some code, you need to post the actual code. Not a partial part of some different code which doesn't even (in this example) actually have the piece of fucntionality until scrutiny, ie: a submit button). What are you expecting us to do with this code? (serious question). Can I recommend you read this, and revise hyour question: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html, including everything I link to in it.

Comment: I recommend you pare-back your code to solely the relevant bits which demonstrate the problem (both to yourself, and to us). Along the way you will quite possibly work out the issue for yourself, but if not, you'll have a good succinct bit of code to show us, and that we can run and see the same thing you are.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Start by cfdumping your form.  Then, when you get to if else stuff, output things like yes and no to see what happened at those points.

Comment: This is paired back. If I give less you would all say I need more. The issue is somewhere in the cfif. If I have only one submit it works fine. When I added the second submit that is when neither would work. The question remains. How do I have two submits on a self submitting page where there are two different database updates. IF the issue is not in the cfif then what do you recommend for the question how do I add two submits to a self submitting coldfusion form?

Comment: The problem I think is that both values for the submits exist on the page and so when I say cfif form.go EQ 1 this is true but so is cfif form.go EQ 2. Is there way around this? If I change the values that will not make a difference.

Comment: I *made* a recommendation, but you chose to ignore it. I also note your CFML at the top of the example isn't actually valid (ie: it would not even compile), so this isn't the code you're running. You're kinda wasting everyone's time here. Post the actual code, having first got rid of everything that doesn't actually contribute to the situation (like mark-up unrelating to the issue). You should ALREADY be doing this as part of your own troubleshooting. Unless you provide coherent code that shows the problem, how can one help you? Did you read those links I pointed you to?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<cfif cgi.request_method EQ "post" AND form.go EQ 1>
    <!--- Do 1 --->
</cfif>

<cfif cgi.request_method EQ "post" AND form.go EQ 2>
    <!--- Do 2 --->
</cfif>




<form action="" method="post">

    <!--- checkbox and whatever else --->

    <button name="go" value="1">Action 1</button>
    <button name="go" value="2">Action 2</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I do not see any form element with name "GO". Only place I see is within  tag which apparently will not be identified by CF. If you want 2 submit buttons and both leading to different actions, you can name them differently like

```
<input type="submit" name="AcceptBtn" value="Accept">
<input type="submit" name="RejectBtn" value="Reject">
```

now on form submit:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form,"AcceptBtn")>
do first action
<cfelseif structKeyExists(form,"RejectBtn")>
do another action
</cfif>
```

Answer (score -4):

Form =action"" is blank. Your form doesn't post to anywhere.

I believe you need to populate the action attribute.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, until I tried it.

Comment: An empty 'action' attribute will post back to the same URL

Comment: I thought the same thing and then I read that it can be blank. In production I will add the page name.